# Oracle Connection in DbConext Model code

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oracle

I am creating my DbContext in one MVC program as follows:

```
public class MYDBContext : DbContext
{

  public DbSet<mytable> mytable{get;set;}

}
```

To pick data from table mytable and view in the grid. 
Since I am getting error if using connection string from `Web.config` but that works if I am creating connection in code with `OracleConnection`  object.
Therefore I like to create connection in my DbContext class code and use it as we do from connection string by `Web.config`.
My database in Oracle.

my connection code is as follows:

```
string connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = PROTOCOL = TCP)
                                     (HOST = oracleserver)
                                     (PORT = 1521)))
                                     (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)
                                     (SERVICE_NAME = MYSERVER)));
                Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myuser;Password=mypassword;";

OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
```

Actually I want to use this connection in my DbContext class. But how will do it and use in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to connect to the Oracle using the following code:

using (DbConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))

{

```
try

{
    connection.open();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Looking on [ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/net-framework-data-provider-for-oracle/), it seems that the example they have is slightly different, try the following:

```
Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oracleserver)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MYSERVER)));
Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myuser;Password=mypassword;
```

Comment: Actually I want to use this connection in my DbContext class. But how will do it and use in the controller.

Comment: @CrazyC, Can you show the code for your controller.